How on "yarn install" install dependencies with different yarn versions?
My yarn version is 3.3.1.
On package.json file I have some dependencies, like this:
"dependencies": {
    "sampleA": "1.2.3",
    "sampleB": "0.0.4"
}

When I use yarn install it is using yarn version 3.3.1 which is correct. But sampleB is a dependency which is compatible with yarn version 1.22.22 so I get the error sampleB isn't supported by any available resolver.
How can I make it to some dependencies to install with another version of yarn?
Notice: I just want to use yarn install to install all, not to install one by one and changing the yarn versions.
